# Primefaces Dialog content not empty after escaping + deleting value

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a dialog which occurs when selecting a row in a datatable (rowselect). It shows metadata of this row and the value comes from the instance which is selected. But when i´m closing this dialog and click my button which should show the same dialog but without any value (to put in data & save), the old one is showed.

I already set the instance null, so that there should not be any value in the outputfields but still same

```
public void newMember(){
    memberInstance=null;
    // RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().reset("memberDllg");

    RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    requestContext.execute("memberDlg.show()");

}
```

and

```
<h:form id="memberDllg">
        <p:dialog id="memberDlg" 
            header="#{AdminControllBean.memberInstance.name} #{AdminControllBean.memberInstance.vorname}"
            widgetVar="memberDlg" rendered="true" closeOnEscape="true"
            style="width:99% !important; height:99% !important;"
            resizable="false">
```

i also tried it with following in facelet, but then full dialog was empty (except of header, which still had old value)

```
onHide="PF('memberDlg').content.empty()">
```

Comment: Are you using update in your buttons to update the dialog components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `update` attribute in your buttons so you update the value of components, something like this:

```
<p:commandButton update="dialogid" ... />
```